# APK has a tv launcher and should be published as an app bundle

Tags: android, store, playback, launcher, television

I'm trying to publish apk to play store, but I'm getting such error
APK has a tv launcher and should be published as an app bundle.

But the app not haven't any tv launchers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
```

in any of your Android manifests?
Remove it if you have it.

If you are using Unity you should also disable Android TV Compatibility